# Avoid ORA-00904 - invalid identifier error while doing sql query in java as the column may or may not be preset in the database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ora-00904

I am trying to write `java` code to migrate data from `oracle database` to other database.
My use case is that different client have different version of code and so the database columns may vary. Clients with later version have additional column.
For eg : Client with new version as `COL99` in the table `SAMPLE_TABLE`.

While writing the migration code, if I try to select the `COL99` from `SAMPLE_TABLE`, it will work fine for the new client. But for clients on old version, the code fails with

> ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier error.

Is there a way to handle in `sql` query or `java` code such that, if the column doesn't exist in the database table, simply ignore and do not return the value instead of throwing the exception.

Comment: Presumably, you'd want to query all_tab_columns in oracle first to see if the column exists or not, rather than doing this as after-the-fact error handling.

Comment: Do you maintain any table for identifying the version of your application?

Comment: @JoshEller agree, that is a possible solution. but i have many tables and many columns in the migration project. So this approach is less feasible.

Answer (score 1):

You should first check, whether `COL99` exists for your current database connection.
For Oracle you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  COL.COLUMN_ID,
  COL.OWNER AS SCHEMA_NAME,
  COL.TABLE_NAME,
  COL.COLUMN_NAME
FROM
  SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS COL
  INNER JOIN
  SYS.ALL_TABLES T 
  ON COL.OWNER = T.OWNER
     AND
     COL.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
WHERE
  COL.OWNER = 'SCHEMA'
  AND
  COL.TABLE_NAME = 'SAMPLE_TABLE'
  AND
  COL.COLUMN_NAME = 'COL99'
```

Then you create your query with or without `COL99`.

Comment: This approach is a possible solution. but in our migration project we have many tables and many columns. Query will become very complicated and not very clean.

Comment: It think, there is no way to ignore missing columns in queries. Maybe it is more convenient for you to add missing columns beforehand (with an appropriate default value) so you can leave the queries unchanged.